# IllegalStateException: unknown destination during restore

Tags: android, navigation, androidx

I'm using Android's Navigation Component (`androidx.navigation`) and I also have bottom navigation menu with 3 items initially (and, respectively, my navigation graph layout has 3 destinations initially). But under some circumstances, I programmatically create the 4th item in the bottom navigation menu and at the same time I add a new destination to navigation graph:

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host)
navController.graph.addDestination(
                FragmentNavigator(this@MainActivity, supportFragmentManager, R.id.nav_host)
                    .createDestination()
                    .apply {
                        id = R.id.action_forth
                        className = "package.MyForthFragment"
                        label = getString(R.string.res_4th_label)
                    })

bottomNavigationView.menu
            .add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_forth, FORTH_ITEM_POSITION, R.string.res_4th_label)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bottom_nav_4_item)
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                someAction()
                true
            }
```

All works fine, but if I rotate device, app is crashing with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4919)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1702)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unknown destination during restore: package:id/action_forth
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:506)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:482)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:447)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:429)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:226)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1418)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3774)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:405)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:387)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at package.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:162)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4919)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1702)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this bug solved in [2.1.0-alpha04](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.1.0-alpha04)

Try to update your navigation dependencies to this version.